# Duplicate named range based off of cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on updating an Excel spreadsheet for my supervisor and I want to find a way to get a named range from another sheet depending on the day of the week (each named range has the name of a weekday) but I haven't found a way to do this.

[image]

So I need the staff list to be duplicated under the weekday heading based on the heading. Any help appreciated, I don't have a huge deal of experience with Excel or VBA.

Comment: @braX Mostly I have been trying to do this via formulae since I'm out of practise with vba. I have been trying to use indirect but all the examples I found have been to do with calculations vased off of a named range i.e. sum of indirect named range.

Comment: Your Excel version has Dynamic Array Formulas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if I understood what you are looking for! If your Excel version has Dynamic Array Formulas then you can try this:

[image]

Comment: That did what I wanted to and it was super easy, thanks!